# Stochastic/markov processes problem and solution book

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Anyone know of any books out there that are primarily just problem and solution books on stochastic processes Markov chains?

Comment: Along with @Daniel S.'s references also look into, "Probability and statistics part 2: Markov Chains" by Suhov and Kelbert. And also Markov Chains, stochastic processes authored by Nicolas Privault

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option

One Hundred Solved Exercises for the subject:
Stochastic Processes

https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/150/takis_exercises.pdf

Check also Grinstead and Snell’s Introduction to Probability

https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf

The classic Kemeny and Snell has many exercises

[https://www.amazon.com/Finite-Markov-Chains-Generalization-Undergraduate/dp/0387901922](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387901922)

https://docs.ufpr.br/~lucambio/CE222/1S2014/Kemeny-Snell1976.pdf